# R: Combining Nested List Elements by Name

Tags: r

Let's say I have a list structure where there are `data.frames` nested in each element.

```
l <- list(A = list(D = data.frame(V1 = seq(3), V2 = LETTERS[1:3]),
                   E = data.frame(V1 = seq(3), V2 = LETTERS[4:6])),
          B = list(D = data.frame(V1 = seq(3), V2 = LETTERS[7:9]),
                   E = data.frame(V1 = seq(3), V2 = LETTERS[10:12])))

$A
$A$D
  V1 V2
1  1  A
2  2  B
3  3  C

$A$E
  V1 V2
1  1  D
2  2  E
3  3  F


$B
$B$D
  V1 V2
1  1  G
2  2  H
3  3  I

$B$E
  V1 V2
1  1  J
2  2  K
3  3  L
```

I would like to find a way to combine the `D` and `E` `data.frames` respectively from the parent list elements (`A`,`B`) so the output would be like this:

```
$D
  V1 V2
1  1  A
2  2  B
3  3  C
4  1  G
5  2  H
6  3  I

$E
  V1 V2
1  1  D
2  2  E
3  3  F
4  1  J
5  2  K
6  3  L
```

I can accomplish this with a loop but I am trying to find something a little more efficient/elegant.

```
out <- vector("list", length(list))
for(i in c("D","E")){
  out[[i]] <- do.call("rbind", lapply(l, function(x) x[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We flatten the nested `list` to a single `list` with 4 elements (`l1`), then `split` 'l1' by the names of the 'l1' after replacing the prefix part up to `.` using `sub`.   Then, we `rbind` the nested `list` using `do.call`.

```
l1 <- do.call('c', l)
lapply(split(l1,sub('.*\\.', '', names(l1))),
                      function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

---

This can be also done with `purrr` and `dplyr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
transpose(l) %>%
          map(bind_rows)
#$D
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

#     V1    V2
#  (int) (chr)
#1     1     A
#2     2     B
#3     3     C
#4     1     G
#5     2     H
#6     3     I

#$E
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

#     V1    V2
#  (int) (chr)
#1     1     D
#2     2     E
#3     3     F
#4     1     J
#5     2     K
#6     3     L
```

Comment: Nice, could you explain the regex a little bit?  I am not as familiar with it.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a more elegant approach with data.table (not necessarily more efficient):

```
library(data.table)

lapply(c('E','D'), function(u) rbindlist(lapply(l, `[[`, u)))
#$A
#   V1 V2
#1:  1  D
#2:  2  E
#3:  3  F
#4:  1  J
#5:  2  K
#6:  3  L

#$B
#   V1 V2
#1:  1  A
#2:  2  B
#3:  3  C
#4:  1  G
#5:  2  H
#6:  3  I
```

In base R, this can be done with

```
lapply(c('E','D'), function(u) do.call(rbind, lapply(l, `[[`, u)))
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is more efficient:

```
l1 <- unlist(l, recursive = FALSE)
D <- do.call(rbind, l1[grepl("\\.D", names(l1))])
E <- do.call(rbind, l1[grepl("\\.E", names(l1))])
```

If important, you'd need to fix the row names subsequently.