# R - Combine arbitrary lists element by element with respect to matched names

Tags: r

I have two lists

```
m = list( 'a' = list( 'b' = list( 1, 2 ), 'c' = 3, 'b1' = 4, 'e' = 5 ) )

n = list( 'a' = list( 'b' = list( 10, 20 ), 'c' = 30, 'b1' = 40 ), 'f' = 50 )
```

Where the structure of m is:

```
List of 1
 $ a:List of 4
  ..$ b :List of 2
  .. ..$ : num 1
  .. ..$ : num 2
  ..$ c : num 3
  ..$ b1: num 4
  ..$ e : num 5
```

And the structure of n is:

```
List of 2
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ b :List of 2
  .. ..$ : num 10
  .. ..$ : num 20
  ..$ c : num 30
  ..$ b1: num 40
 $ f: num 50
```

Want a combined output like this. Also the solution should be general for deeply nested lists.

Expected output :

```
List of 2


$ a:List of 4
  ..$ b :List of 4
  .. ..$ : num 1
  .. ..$ : num 2
  .. ..$ : num 10
  .. ..$ : num 20
  ..$ c : num [1:2] 3 30
  ..$ b1: num [1:2] 4 40
  ..$ e : num 5
 $ f: num 50
```

Have seen this, but it is not general enough for deeply nested lists

[R: Combining Nested List Elements by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395041/r-combining-nested-list-elements-by-name)

Comment: In the expected output, why is the "f" inside "a" list?

Comment: "f" is an element in n. Hence it is included.

Comment: I understand why it is included, I am questioning why it is **not** in the same level as "a" in expected output.

Comment: The point is that `f` should be at the same level as `a`.

Comment: Understood. Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a recursive way to do it:

```
mergeList <- function(x, y){
    if(is.list(x) && is.list(y) && !is.null(names(x)) && !is.null(names(y))){
        ecom <- intersect(names(x), names(y))
        enew <- setdiff(names(y), names(x))
        res <- x
        if(length(enew) > 0){
            res <- c(res, y[enew])
        }
        if(length(ecom) > 0){
            for(i in ecom){
                res[i] <- list(mergeList(x[[i]], y[[i]]))
            }
        }
        return(res)
    }else{
        return(c(x, y))
    }
}

m = list( 'a' = list( 'b' = list( 1, 2 ), 'c' = 3, 'b1' = 4, 'e' = 5 ) )
n = list( 'a' = list( 'b' = list( 10, 20 ), 'c' = 30, 'b1' = 40 ), 'f' = 50 )
mn <- mergeList(m, n)

str(mn)
# List of 2
#  $ a:List of 4
#   ..$ b :List of 4
#   .. ..$ : num 1
#   .. ..$ : num 2
#   .. ..$ : num 10
#   .. ..$ : num 20
#   ..$ c : num [1:2] 3 30
#   ..$ b1: num [1:2] 4 40
#   ..$ e : num 5
#  $ f: num 50
```

In case you have multiple nested lists (`m1`, `m2` and `m3`, for example) to merge, `Reduce` could be helpful:

```
Reduce(mergeList, list(m1, m2, m3))
```

Comment: This works good. Can we have a generalized version of this ? Where instead of m and n, there will be m1, m2, m3, m4, ..... etc. @mt1022 can we expand this please.

Comment: @SoumyaBoral, You can generalize it with `Reduce`: `Reduce(mergeList, list(m1, m2, m3, ...))`

Comment: Doesn't this 'strip' attributes from the lists?  Or does it also merge the attributes?

Comment: @mshaffer I didn't test how this influence list attributes. You can give it a try and ask a new question is you have any problem :)